# How to use join to select like count of returned message rows

Tags: php, sql, join, select, count

**Context**

I'm having trouble understanding the application of the JOIN statement when I try to return rows of message values and find their corresponding like counts, which are stored in a different table. The first table I'm trying to pull from is one that contains the messages I want:

```
SELECT forums.forum_id, forums.message FROM forums LIMIT 3
```

I'm then trying to use the resulting `forum_id` values to insert into the second query, which obtains the like counts:

```
SELECT COUNT(forumvotes.forum_id) AS voteCount FROM forumvotes JOIN forums ON forumvotes.forum_id = forums.forum_id 
WHERE forumvotes.forum_id = [insert returned forum ids here]
```

**Question**

I believe that I can combine these two queries into one by using a join, but I'm unsure of how to do it. When I combine the two like so, the new `voteCount` column returns the count of all the forum votes that have been inserted, not just the count of the likes of the three specific messages I want:

```
SELECT forums.forum_id, forums.message, 
(SELECT COUNT(forumvotes.forum_id) AS voteCount FROM forumvotes JOIN forums ON forumvotes.forum_id = forums.forum_id WHERE forumvotes.forum_id = forums.forum_id) AS voteCount 
FROM forums LIMIT 3
```

So, the query returns three rows, each of which contains the invididual messages (which is good), but they also return the same `voteCount` value of 13 because there have been 13 likes inserted into the database, but each row's `voteCount` value should only be one or two because each message only has one or two likes.

How can I combine these two queries into one? Let me know if there's any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly *correlate* the subquery with the outer query. The problem is that you are using the same alias for the outer and inner, so the condition in the `WHERE` clause does not actually filter anything. You should be using table aliases to avoid this problem.

Is is unnecessary to use the `forum` table in the subquery anyway. You can write this as:

```
SELECT 
    f.forum_id, 
    f.message, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM forumvotes fv 
        WHERE fv.forum_id = f.forum_id
    ) AS voteCount 
FROM forums f
ORDER BY ??
LIMIT 3
```

You would also need an `ORDER BY` clause if you want results that are consistent over consecutive executions.

Answer (score 1):

From how you describe this, you would be looking to do an "IN" sub-query here.

```
SELECT COUNT(forumvotes.forum_id) AS voteCount FROM forumvotes 
WHERE forumvotes.forum_id IN (SELECT forums.forum_id, forums.message FROM forums LIMIT 3)
```

Specifically what this will be doing is returning only the ids of the first three forum rows, and joining them with some forum information

Answer (score 1):

I `JOIN` the forums table to a nested query that holds the `COUNT, GROUP BY` each `forum_id`

```
SELECT f.forum_id, f.message, a.voteCount
  FROM forums f
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(forumvotes.forum_id) AS voteCount, forumvotes.forum_id
          FROM forumvotes
         GROUP BY forumvotes.forum_id) a ON f.forum_id = a.forum_id
```